# On JIRA, can I have a column in my agile board based on a filter and not (only) on a status?

Tags: jira, tools

I want to create a board with different columns, but all of them have the same status, but belong to different "teams". So I'd like to have a column for each team. Is it possible to create a column based on a filter/query and not only on a status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't believe that is possible. Furthermore, I don't see how it *could* be.

Consider the situation where you have two separate 'filter-columns', and a given story fits *both* filters. What would happen? Would it show up *twice*?

As an alternative, you could just add more statuses - 'In Progress Team A', 'In Progress Team B', etc. Simplest thing to do from there is just to include two statuses in each column, and each Team will drag theirs to the correct one when they move it. There might also be a way to automate it based on workflow and currently logged-in user.

Comment: To add to this, another thing you can do is use JQL queries for your swimlanes. For example, I recently built a board to track a cross team project and each swimlane is set to show "project = 'projectname'" so I can see each teams progress all on the same board. Just configure your board, go to swimlanes, and set the type to "Queries" and add your filter.

Answer (score 2):

For exactly this situation, JIRA offers quick filters for Agile Board. What I do is add these filters according to the team and then you see the status for each of the team.
This can be accessed by 
[image]

Which will take you to board configuration where you can add Quick Filters.
[image]

Now the filter is visible on the top of the board.
For more detail, please refer [Atlassian Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/configuring-a-board/configuring-quick-filters)